# Display Combobox values from numbers

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have a int value which I want to use for configuration. It can have 2 values - 0 for active and 1 for Blocked. I want to display this into friendly combo box:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        int state = 0;

        ObservableList<String> options = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "Active",
            "Blocked"
        );
        ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox(options);
        BorderPane bp = new BorderPane(comboBox);
        bp.setPrefSize(800, 800);
        Scene scene = new Scene(bp);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

It's not clear for me how I have to implement this into JavaFX Combobox.
When I have 0 I want to display this as `Active` and when I have 1 I want to display `Blocked` and also when I change the ComboBox value to update also `int state` value.

Comment: Why don't you create a CustomObject which stores the string and its corresponding value? Later, you can create an ObservableList<CustomObject> and assign it to the ComboBox. This will make things easier for you.

Comment: I agree but it's a little advanced for me. Can you give me a hand please?

Comment: If your data are Integers, let the items _be_ of type Integer. Then use a converter to display them as needed.

Comment: Why are the data integers to begin with? Surely for this kind of functionality you should use an `enum`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to solve this problem. I have listed three of the solutions below. You can use any one of the below solutions which you feel is apt for your scenario.

### Using a custom class

Create a custom class `KeyValuePair`, for storing the string and its corresponding value. Exposed the getters for the required fields.

Later, I have used the `setCellFactory()` of the comboxbox to show the required data. Use StringConverter to show the key in place of the object.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        KeyValuePair keyValuePair1 = new KeyValuePair("Active", 0);
        KeyValuePair keyValuePair2 = new KeyValuePair("Blocked", 1);


        ObservableList<KeyValuePair> options = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        options.addAll(keyValuePair1, keyValuePair2);

        ComboBox<KeyValuePair> comboBox = new ComboBox<>(options);

        // show the correct text
        comboBox.setCellFactory((ListView<KeyValuePair> param) -> {
            final ListCell<KeyValuePair> cell = new ListCell<KeyValuePair>(){

                @Override
                protected void updateItem(KeyValuePair t, boolean bln) {
                    super.updateItem(t, bln);

                    if(t != null){
                        setText(String.valueOf(t.getKey()));
                    }else{
                        setText(null);
                    }
                }

            };
            return cell;
        });


        comboBox.setConverter(new StringConverter<KeyValuePair>() {
            @Override
            public String toString(KeyValuePair object) {
                return object.getKey();
            }

            @Override
            public KeyValuePair fromString(String string) {
                return null; // No conversion fromString needed.
            }
        });


        // print the value
        comboBox.valueProperty().addListener((ov, oldVal, newVal) -> {
            System.out.println(newVal.getKey() + " - " + newVal.getValue());
        });

        BorderPane bp = new BorderPane(comboBox);
        bp.setPrefSize(800, 800);
        Scene scene = new Scene(bp);
            stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    class KeyValuePair {
        private final String key;
        private final int value;

        public KeyValuePair(String key, int value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

### Without using an extra class

As suggested by @kleopatra, you can even do this without using an extra class.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        ObservableList<Integer> options = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        options.addAll(1, 0);

        ComboBox<Integer> comboBox = new ComboBox<>(options);

        // show the correct text
        comboBox.setCellFactory((ListView<Integer> param) -> {
            final ListCell<Integer> cell = new ListCell<Integer>(){

                @Override
                protected void updateItem(Integer t, boolean bln) {
                    super.updateItem(t, bln);

                    if(t != null){
                        setText(t == 1 ? "Active" : "Blocked");
                    }else{
                        setText(null);
                    }
                }

            };
            return cell;
        });


        comboBox.setConverter(new StringConverter<Integer>() {
              @Override
              public String toString(Integer object) {
                  return object == 1 ? "Active" : "Blocked";
              }

              @Override
              public Integer fromString(String string) {
                  return null;
              }
        });

        // print the value
        comboBox.valueProperty().addListener((ov, oldVal, newVal) -> {
            System.out.println("Changed from " + oldVal + " to " + newVal);
        });

        BorderPane bp = new BorderPane(comboBox);
        bp.setPrefSize(800, 800);
        Scene scene = new Scene(bp);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

### Using Bindings

You can also use Bindings if you don't want to take the pain of creating a new class and you will **always** have two elements i.e. Active and Blocked.

Just bind the valueProperty() of your combobox to the state, which is supposed to store the value i.e. 0 or 1.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        IntegerProperty state = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        ObservableList options = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Active", "Blocked");

        ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>(options);
        state.bind(Bindings.when(comboBox.valueProperty().isEqualTo("Active")).then(0).otherwise(1));

        BorderPane bp = new BorderPane(comboBox);
        bp.setPrefSize(800, 800);
        Scene scene = new Scene(bp);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! One quick question, are there any other available solutions? Just to know in future if I have the similar case?

Comment: @PeterPenzov Added an alternate solution,  it is simpler and may be suits your query better.

Comment: As I have already said in the answer, if you have just 2 values you can use the Bindings but if the scope increases and you need multiple values, you should go with the class approach.

Comment: -1 - never-ever override toString for ui reasons - that's not scaleable in any way and blows into your face if there are different display requirements!

Comment: @kleopatra Yeah, you are right. I just happened to miss that. Edited my answer to use a more elegant StringConverter instead.

Comment: darn ... 5 min grace period for comment editing is just too short ;-) Removed my downvote, though your solution is still not optimal: there is no need for that additional class, the converter can handle _any_ conversion. Simply let the items be ints (the raw data) and implement a custom converter to display the values as needed.

Comment: @kleopatra added as an alternate approach, hope it is optimal now ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution:

declare state as `BooleanProperty`:

```
   private BooleanProperty state = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
```

bind state property to the valueProperty of comboBox:

```
 comboBox.valueProperty().bind(new When(state).then("Active").otherwise("Blocked"));
```

**complete example:**

```
public class ComboboxTest extends Application {

    private BooleanProperty state = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
    private Button button;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        ObservableList<String> options = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                "Active",
                "Blocked"
        );
        ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox(options);
        button = new Button("false");
        button.setOnAction(e -> setSate());
        button.textProperty().bind(state.asString());
        BorderPane bp = new BorderPane(comboBox);
        StackPane stackpane = new StackPane(button);
        stackpane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        bp.setTop(stackpane);
        bp.setPrefSize(800, 800);
        Scene scene = new Scene(bp);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        comboBox.valueProperty().bind(new When(state).then("Active").otherwise("Blocked"));
    }

    public void setSate() {
        if (state.get()) {
            state.set(false);

        } else {
            state.set(true);
        }
    }

}
```