# How to SetValue Of ComboBox With Given Id Value ?

Tags: javafx, combobox, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have tried the code to create a combobox with Id and Value Pair. Now I want to set the value of combobox with the specified Id passed. Example: I want to set the Value of combobox with employee name whose salary is 1400.0

```
package demo;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author vikassingh
 */
public class Demo extends Application {

    private final ObservableList<Employee> data
            = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                    new Employee("Azamat", 2200.15),
                    new Employee("Veli", 1400.0),
                    new Employee("Nurbek", 900.5));

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ComboBox<Employee> combobox = new ComboBox<>(data);

        // testing
        //combobox.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
        //combobox.setValue(1400.0); // How to set value with specific Id Passed
        // End testing

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(combobox);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static class Employee {

        private String name;
        private Double salary;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }

        public Employee(String name, Double salary) {
            this.name = name;
            this.salary = salary;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Double getSalary() {
            return salary;
        }

        public void setSalary(Double salary) {
            this.salary = salary;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display Combobox values from numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32561396/display-combobox-values-from-numbers)

Comment: If you have setters for the `"Employee`'s properties, you should implement the properties as javafx properties, since this is an easy way to add the observer pattern to your class, which is needed to update the view properly. Also: is this about displaying the `Employee`s properly or about finding the one with the correct salary?

Comment: @fabian : It's about finding the employee with correct salary, please give some code, so that I can try it.

Answer (score 2):

Finding the correct `Employee` in the `data` list can be done using the same technique you'd use for any other `Collection` / `List`: iterate through the collection and find the first element that matches the criterion. The Streams API provides a simple way to do this:

```
Predicate<Employee> matcher = employee -> employee.getSalary() == 1400d;
Optional<Employee> opt = data.stream().filter(matcher).findAny();

combobox.setValue(opt.orElse(null)); // set found employee or null, if none was found.
```