# setValue of a Non-editable comboBox

Tags: combobox, javafx-8

Can someone share some sample codes on how to set the value of a non-editable Combobox? It is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35953811/how-to-setvalue-of-combobox-with-given-id-value), but when I tried to insert it in my code. It returns a null value

**Code**

```
ObservableList<City> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
data = AddressGetWay.getCityByProvince("Batanes")
cmbCity.setItems(data); // set the items from the database

cmbCity.setConverter(new StringConverter<City>() {

        @Override
        public String toString(City object) {
                return object.getCityName();
        }

        @Override
        public City fromString(String string) {
               return cmbCity.getItems().stream().filter(ap
                      -> ap.getCityName().equals(string)).findFirst().orElse(null);
        }
 });

cmbCity.valueProperty().addListener(
    (ObservableValue<? extends City> observable, City oldValue, City newVal) -> {
       if (newVal != null) {
          //
        }
     }
);

// TODO: get the data stored in the database (Column City)
//  and set the value of the ComboBox.

Predicate<City> predicate = city -> city.getCityName() == "Itbayat"; // Let's assume that the data stored in the database is "Itbayat"
Optional<City> opt = data.stream().filter(predicate).findAny();
cmbCity.getSelectionModel().select(opt.orElse(null)); // the ComboBox value should be "Itbayat".
```

I'm using a Singleton Class (correct me if I'm wrong) to retrieve the data from the database

```
public class AddressGetWay {

    static Connection con; //connect to the database
    static PreparedStatement pst = null;
    static ResultSet rs = null;

    public static ObservableList<City> getCityByProvince(String prov) {
        ObservableList<City> listData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        String sql = "SELECT pk_cit_id, cit_nm, zip_code FROM city_mun WHERE prov_code = (SELECT prov_code FROM provinces WHERE prov_nm = ?)";

        try {
            pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, prov);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                listData.add(new City(
                        rs.getInt(1),
                        rs.getString(2),
                        rs.getInt(3)
                ));
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AddressGetWay.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                pst.close();
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(AddressGetWay.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        return listData;
    }
}
```

This should be my desired Output

[image: desired output]

But  I got this output using the above code

[image: my output]

As for my naming conventions. I tried to do [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/) if there's something I need to correct, feel free to pinpoint.

Comment: Iirc this is not the first time you post code that doesn't compile. `'` quotes denote `char` literals in java and they cannot contain multiple chars in java. Please produce a [mcve] that you actually verified results in the the behaviour. Also I'm sure kleopatra has informed you of the benefit of adhering to java naming conventions...

Comment: I think either `AddressGetWay.getCityByProvince("Batanes")` is not retrieving anything or `Itbayat` is not matching. please try to debug `Optional<City> opt = data.stream().filter(predicate).findAny();`  and see the database value as well

Comment: @ShekharRai finally got the answer. I'll try to post my answer soon after I trim down my codes. Technically, I just only need to call the `getter` on my object `Province`, as I use an Object variable. (`private Province provName();`) - _same as the `City`_.  Also, thanks for the edit, finally have a clue on naming conventions 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are having issue on this code block,

```
ObservableList<City> data = AddressGetWay.getCityByProvince("Batanes");

//....

Predicate<City> predicate = city -> city.getCityName() == "Itbayat";
Optional<City> opt = data.stream().filter(predicate).findAny();
cmbCity.getSelectionModel().select(opt.orElse(null));
```

I suspect some `loop-holes` that is overcoming the `null-value`.

- As you retrieving data through province *Batanes* i.e. `ObservableList<City> data = AddressGetWay.getCityByProvince("Batanes")`, maybe it's not retrieving any data.
- Your predicate is comparing cityName *Itbayat*, which may not be getting matched with the retrieved data.
- Please check the database value for the city table as to compare those data as well

**AddressGateWay**

```
public class AddressGateWay {

    private static Connection connection;
    private static PreparedStatement statement = null;
    private static ResultSet result = null;

    static {
        connection = loadConnection();
    }

    public static ObservableList<City> getCityByProvince(String prov) {
        ObservableList<City> listData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        String sql = "SELECT pk_cit_id, cit_nm, zip_code FROM city_mun WHERE prov_code = (SELECT prov_code FROM provinces WHERE prov_nm = ?)";

        try {
            statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setString(1, prov);
            result = statement.executeQuery();

            while (result.next()) {
                listData.add(new City(
                        result.getInt(1),
                        result.getString(2)
                ));
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AddressGateWay.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                statement.close();
                result.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(AddressGateWay.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        return listData;
    }

    // for editing
    public static ObservableList<Address> selectedItem(int item) {
            ObservableList<Address> listData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            String sql = "SELECT prov_nm, city_nm FROM emp_address WHERE pk_address_id = ?";

            try {
                statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                statement.setString(1, item);
                result = statement.executeQuery();

                if (result.next()) {
                    listData.add(new Address(
                            result.getString(1),
                            result.getString(2)
                    ));
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(AddressGateWay.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } finally {
                try {
                    statement.close();
                    result.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(AddressGateWay.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
            return listData;
        }
}
```

**City**

```
public class City {
    private int id;
    private String cityName;

    public City(int id, String cityName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.cityName = cityName;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCityName() {
        return cityName;
    }

    public void setCityName(String cityName) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
    }
}
```

**Controller Logic Code**

```
ObservableList<City> cities = AddressGateWay.getCityByProvince(provinceComboBox.getValue()); // assume the value is "Batanes"
    cityComboBox.setItems(cities);

cityComboBox.setConverter(new StringConverter<City>() {
    @Override
    public String toString(City object) {
        return object.getCityName();
    }

    @Override
    public City fromString(String string) {
        return cityComboBox.getItems().stream().filter(ap
                -> ap.getCityName().equals(string)).findFirst().orElse(null);
    }
});
cityComboBox.valueProperty().addListener(
        (ObservableValue<? extends City> observable, City oldValue, City newVal) -> {
            if (newVal != null) {
                //
            }
        }
);

City city = cities
        .stream()
        .filter(c -> c.getCityName() == "Itbayat")
        .findAny()
        .orElse(null);

cityComboBox.getSelectionModel().select(city);



// summing up the below updates and your codes,
// I have set the value of cityComboBox by using . . .

Address ads = new Address();
ads = AddressGetWay.selectedItem(item); // the item to be edit

// assume the value from the database is "Itbayat"
Predicate<City> predicate = city -> city.getCityName() == ads.getCity().getCityName();

Optional<City> opt = cities.stream().filter(predicate).findAny();

cityComboBox.getSelectionModel().select(opt.orElse(null));

// Thank you, it finally work :)
```

**Some key points based on the updated code**

- Refactoring code based on unnecessary code
- Implementing basic Java naming Conventions
- Missing connection initialization (need to load based on your database)
- Inined code (for Predicate, and Optional)

**EDIT**

**Province**

```
public class Province {
     private String provinceCode;
     private String provinceName;

     //Constructors
     //Getters and Setters
}
```

**Address**

```
public class Address {
     private City city;
     private Province province;

     //Constructors
     //Getters and Setters

}
```

Comment: For my `class City`, I actually use an Object variable for `province`. So it was like `private Province province;`. Now the reason why I can't retrieve the same String variable as the one on the combobox list was that, I forgot to call the Province. So it should be `filter (c -> c.getCityName() == provinceCombobox.getProvince().getProvinceName()`. But in my code, I have to call for new Instance `new Province(provinceCombobox.getProvince()`. which is totally wrong. But still, how can I not retrieve the data `"Itbayat"`? when I click the dropdown, I can see the `Itbayat` on the list

Comment: @miKeL *how can I not retrieve the data "Itbayat"?* - still having the issue()? need help?

Comment: the problem already solved :) thanks to you. I'm just wondering, isn't it the same as when I wrote `"Itbayat"` rather than  `provinceCombobox.getProvince().getProvinceName()` on the relational operator (**==**) should have the same output?

Comment: Yes! but you need to do `provinceCombobox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().province.getProvinceName()` instead of `provinceCombobox.getProvince().getProvinceName()` - which gives you the currently selected `province`.